# Provide token with identity server 4 only if the user fulfills certain conditions

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I made a reasearch for about a week and i didn't find any solution to my question.

I'm using a ASP.NET Core Identity on .NET Core 2 Api and an identity server 4 to authenticate a user from the Angular 4 client app.

My question is:
Is there any solution to provide a token from the `/connect/token` endpoint to a user only if he fulfills certain values from the database (e.g. `EmailConfirmed` is 1 (true) and so on).

If I wasn't clear enough please leave a comment below.

Comment: Also, can i made SQL Queries at the identity server level, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IProfileService` as an extension point.

The `IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity` package already provides an `ProfileService<TUser>` (see [source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/2.1.0/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/ProfileService.cs)) class which can be extended with the desired behavior.

There you can override the `IsActiveAsync` method and add your desired logic.

```
public class ConfirmedUsersProfileService : ProfileService<TUser>
{
    public override async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null && user.EmailConfirmed == true;
    }
}
```

When the user is either not existing in the database or his email is not confirmed, he won't be signed in and hence, no token be returned.

This is also clearly described in the official [Identity4 Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/profileservice.html).

> `IsActiveAsync`
>
> The API that is expected to indicate if a user is currently allowed to obtain tokens. It is passed an instance of `IsActiveContext`.

Then register the new `ConfirmedUsersProfileService` instead of the old service:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    ...
    .AddProfileService<ConfirmedUsersProfileService>();
```

> Also, can i made SQL Queries at the identity server level, somehow?

Yes, you can inject any service into the `ConfirmedUsersProfileService`, i.e. the `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` or `UserManager<TUser>` (which is already injected, you just need to hold a reference to it in your derived class, as the fields in the `ProfileService<TUser>` are marked as private.) and then perform any query on it.

**P.S.** The `IProfileService` can and should also be used as token extension points. You can add additional (or remove existing) claims from the token at this point too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but meanwhile i managed to override IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator interface and i did the logic there. Now my wish is to add some claims when the token is generated.
I added this way : 
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                        {
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, user.PhoneNumber),
                         };
                        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.UserName, "password", claims);.
When i am in the controller i don't see any claim in the HTTPContext.User, do you know why?

Comment: You can't add claims in the controller, by the time you  hit the controller the claims principal and the tokens were already created. You should use the above `IProfileService` to add tokens when they are requested from the **identity server**.